# Рекурсивно сравнить элементы массивов

Tags: массивы, delphi, рекурсия

Задача: дано два массива одинаковой длинны. Написать рекурсивную функцию, которая сравнит элементы массива и если все сошлось, то true, а если нет - false. Программа работает неправильно. В данном случае я попробовал заменить второй элемент массива b на "2", но рез-тат все равно true. Подскажите, что не так?

```
    var
  a:array[0..4] of integer;
  b:array[0..4] of integer;
  i:integer;
function check(a,b:array of integer;i:integer):boolean;
begin

  if a[i]=b[i] then
  begin
    result:=true;
    check(a,b,i+1);
  end
  else
  begin
    result:=false;
    exit;
  end;
end;
begin
  for i:=0 to 4 do
    a[i]:=i;
  for i:=0 to 4 do
    b[i]:=i;
  b[1]:=2;
  writeln(check(a,b,0));

  for i:=0 to 4 do
    writeln(a[i], ' = ' , b[i]);
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: >Подскажите, что не так?

почему вы считаете, что что-то не так?

Comment: @DreamChild Потому что программа работает неправильно. Эл a[1]=1,а эл b[1]=2,т.е. не совпадают, а рез-тат программы выводит true, хотя должен false

Comment: тогда напишите это в условии - вы же не предлагаете гадать за вас, что вас не устраивает в поведении вашего кода?

Comment: @DreamChild , прошу прощенья, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцию `Check` нужно переписать так:

```
function Check(Arr1, Arr2: array of integer; n: integer): Boolean;
begin
  if (Length(Arr1) = n) or (Length(Arr2) = n) then
  begin
    if Length(Arr1) = Length(Arr2) then
      Result := True
    else
      Result := False; // массивы разной длинны
  end
  else
    if Arr1[n] = Arr2[n] then
      Result := Check(Arr1, Arr2, n + 1)
    else
      Result := False;
end;
```

P.S.: Не используйте для имен параметров функции имена, совпадающие с именами глобальных переменных (`a`, `b`, `i` в Вашем случае) - это может плохо кончиться :)

Comment: А можно вопрос:  if Length(Arr1) = Length(Arr2) - это для чего нужно так писать? Ведь у нас по дефолту равны?

Comment: Ну вдруг вы захотите сравнить массивы разной длинны. :) Без этой проверки функция вернет `True` если начало длинного массива совпадает по всей длине с коротким массивом. Надеюсь, я понятно описал ситуацию?

Comment: @111xbot111
У вас хе в функции написано `array of integer` а не `array[0..4] of integer`. Так что на вход может придти что угодно )

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, ага, понял. Спасибо!